# Call a function located in a class to another file

Tags: php, function

I have been trying to call this function and get the $id from the function userdata($id) to the function retrieve_proposal_data ($job). All of my efforts are for not. I continue to get an **call to undefined function** error. The first function is located in another file and class. I need to get the $id from that function and call it in my SELECT statement WHERE client_id = $id. I am new to php and especially functions and don't quite know how this is done. I have seacrhed this site and read php cookbook looking for answers but to no avail. There are also other functions in both files but for this question I didn't think there is a need to post them. Anyway any help? Here is my code.

```
// File: login.php

<?php
require 'core/init.php';
$general->logged_in_protect();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, but we need your username and password.';
    } else if ($users->user_exists($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry that username doesn\'t exists.';
    } else if ($users->email_confirmed($username) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, but you need to activate your account. 
                     Please check your email.';
    } else {
        if (strlen($password) > 18) {
            $errors[] = 'The password should be less than 18 characters, without spacing.';
        }
        $login = $users->login($username, $password);
        if ($login === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, that username/password is invalid';
        }else {
            session_regenerate_id(true);// destroying the old session id and creating a new one
            $_SESSION['id'] =  $login;
            header('Location: home.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

and

```
// File: users.php

    <?php 
class Users{

    private $db;

    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->db = $database;
    }   

    public function update_user($first_name, $last_name, $gender, $bio, $image_location, $id){

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET
                                `first_name`    = ?,
                                `last_name`     = ?,
                                `gender`        = ?,
                                `bio`           = ?,
                                `image_location`= ?

                                WHERE `id`      = ? 
                                ");

        $query->bindValue(1, $first_name);
        $query->bindValue(2, $last_name);
        $query->bindValue(3, $gender);
        $query->bindValue(4, $bio);
        $query->bindValue(5, $image_location);
        $query->bindValue(6, $id);

        try{
            $query->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }

    public function change_password($user_id, $password) {

        global $bcrypt;

        /* Two create a Hash you do */
        $password_hash = $bcrypt->genHash($password);

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $password_hash);
        $query->bindValue(2, $user_id);             

        try{
            $query->execute();
            return true;
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function recover($email, $generated_string) {

        if($generated_string == 0){
            return false;
        }else{

            $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `generated_string` = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $email);
            $query->bindValue(2, $generated_string);

            try{

                $query->execute();
                $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

                if($rows == 1){

                    global $bcrypt;

                    $username = $this->fetch_info('username', 'email', $email); // getting username for the use in the email.
                    $user_id  = $this->fetch_info('id', 'email', $email);// We want to keep things standard and use the user's id for most of the operations. Therefore, we use id instead of email.

                    $charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
                    $generated_password = substr(str_shuffle($charset),0, 10);

                    $this->change_password($user_id, $generated_password);

                    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `generated_string` = 0 WHERE `id` = ?");

                    $query->bindValue(1, $user_id);

                    $query->execute();

                    mail($email, 'Your password', "Hello " . $username . ",\n\nYour your new password is: " . $generated_password . "\n\nPlease change your password once you have logged in using this password.\n\n-Example team");

                }else{
                    return false;
                }

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public function fetch_info($what, $field, $value){

        $allowed = array('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'bio', 'email'); // I have only added few, but you can add more. However do not add 'password' eventhough the parameters will only be given by you and not the user, in our system.
        if (!in_array($what, $allowed, true) || !in_array($field, $allowed, true)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException;
        }else{

            $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT $what FROM `users` WHERE $field = ?");

            $query->bindValue(1, $value);

            try{

                $query->execute();

            } catch(PDOException $e){

                die($e->getMessage());
            }

            return $query->fetchColumn();
        }
    }

    public function confirm_recover($email){

        $username = $this->fetch_info('username', 'email', $email);// We want the 'id' WHERE 'email' = user's email ($email)

        $unique = uniqid('',true);
        $random = substr(str_shuffle('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),0, 10);

        $generated_string = $unique . $random; // a random and unique string

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `generated_string` = ? WHERE `email` = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $generated_string);
        $query->bindValue(2, $email);

        try{

            $query->execute();

            mail($email, 'Recover Password', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nPlease click the link below:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.example.com/recover.php?email=" . $email . "&generated_string=" . $generated_string . "\r\n\r\n We will generate a new password for you and send it back to your email.\r\n\r\n-- Example team");           

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function user_exists($username) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function email_exists($email) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email`= ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $email);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch (PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function register($username, $password, $email){

        global $bcrypt; // making the $bcrypt variable global so we can use here

        $time       = time();
        $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // getting the users IP address
        $email_code = $email_code = uniqid('code_',true); // Creating a unique string.

        $password   = $bcrypt->genHash($password);

        $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `ip`, `time`, `email_code`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, $password);
        $query->bindValue(3, $email);
        $query->bindValue(4, $ip);
        $query->bindValue(5, $time);
        $query->bindValue(6, $email_code);

        try{
            $query->execute();

            mail($email, 'Please activate your account', "Hello " . $username. ",\r\nThank you for registering with us. Please visit the link below so we can activate your account:\r\n\r\nhttp://www.example.com/activate.php?email=" . $email . "&email_code=" . $email_code . "\r\n\r\n-- Example team");
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }   
    }

    public function activate($email, $email_code) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ? AND `email_code` = ? AND `confirmed` = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $email);
        $query->bindValue(2, $email_code);
        $query->bindValue(3, 0);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){

                $query_2 = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `confirmed` = ? WHERE `email` = ?");

                $query_2->bindValue(1, 1);
                $query_2->bindValue(2, $email);             

                $query_2->execute();
                return true;

            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }


    public function email_confirmed($username) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ? AND `confirmed` = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);
        $query->bindValue(2, 1);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

            if($rows == 1){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function login($username, $password) {

        global $bcrypt;  // Again make get the bcrypt variable, which is defined in init.php, which is included in login.php where this function is called

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT `password`, `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username);

        try{

            $query->execute();
            $data               = $query->fetch();
            $stored_password    = $data['password']; // stored hashed password
            $id                 = $data['id']; // id of the user to be returned if the password is verified, below.

            if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){ // using the verify method to compare the password with the stored hashed password.
                return $id; // returning the user's id.

            }else{
                return false;   
            }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function userdata($id) {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`= ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
print_r($id);
        try{

            $query->execute();

            return $query->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e){

            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

    public function get_users() {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY `time` DESC");

        try{
            $query->execute();
echo($query); 
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $query->fetchAll();

    }   
}
```

and then

```
// File: retrieval.php

function retrieve_proposal_data($job) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id = $id";
  $stuff = $db->prepare($query);
  $stuff->execute();
  $clientsdata = $stuff->fetch();
}
```

Comment: What version of php are you running/using?

Answer (score 0):

It's inside a class so the class needs to be instantiated then you're able to call the method. Alternatively change it to a static method (public static function ...) and call Users::userdata($id);

Your final option would be to move the method out of the class and then you'll be able to use userdata($id); in the way you're expecting.

```
$Users = new Users();
$userdata = $Users->userdata($id);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with this code. **Warning:** Missing argument 1 for Users::__construct() I dont have any idea what this is

Comment: The construct method isn't shown in your example so I wasn't aware it existed. You'll need to look at the __construct method and see what its arguments are. Can you post the code?

Comment: @ Nathan Dawson Okay I edited my initial post to include all the functions in the Users class.

Comment: @user3135712 It wants you to pass in a database object. Try $Users = new Users( $db );

Comment: I believe that was it but now I'm wondering why the $id in the $userdata = $Users->userdata($id); code is getting **Notice:** Undefined variable: id. But in the users.php file the variable is defined.

Comment: My objective here is after a user has logged in, get the $id and retrieve the users proposal_data WHERE client_id = $id.

Comment: You haven't given $id a value before passing it in to the userdata method. If what you're trying to do is get the ID then this isn't the method you need to be using.

Comment: Okay I'm lost now for sure. As stated before after the user has logged in the $id in the public function userdata($id) code gets the logged in users. How do I get the ID?

Comment: There is also a public function in the general file which has the following: public function logged_in () {
  return(isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
  
 } which is also in a class. I found this login code on the net and trying to use it to pull up user info after the user has logged in.

Comment: When the user logs in their ID is returned. You need to assign it to a variable. You need to post the code in login.php for me to tell you any more than that.

Comment: I got the code from here, take a look and let me know. http://www.sunnytuts.com/article/login-and-registration-with-object-oriented-php-and-pdo-part-2

Comment: The ID you're looking for can be retrieved with $_SESSION['id']